# Chai problem mocking API response - Function is not stubbed

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to test an API response. I don't know if the way that i am mocking req, res is the best way, but my code is:

```
it('should failed when missing auth header', async () => {
  const req = {} as functions.https.Request;
  const res: any = {
    status: function (statusCode: number) {
      assert.strictEqual(statusCode, 401);
      return this;
    },
    send: function (body: unknown) {
      assert.deepEqual(body, {
        error: "Unauthorized",
      });
    },
  };
  await createNudgeBankLinkingNotifications(req, res);
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(res.status);
});
```

but i am receiving this error when i run the test

```
AssertError: function (statusCode) {
                chai_1.assert.equal(statusCode, 401);
                return this;
            } is not stubbed
```

The function that is being tested is:

```
export const createNudgeBankLinkingNotifications = 

functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (!hasAuthHeaderAPIKey(req)) {
    res.status(401).send({
      error: 'Unauthorized'
    });
    return
  }
  const { correlationId } = createFunctionLogger(
    'createNudgeBankLinkingNotifications',
    fileLevelLogger,
  );
  try {
    await sendNudgeBankLinkingNotifications(correlationId);
    res.status(200).send({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      error: 'Notification cannot be sent'
    });
  }
});
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Show the code under test.